# How to clear screen in Julia REPL on Windows

Tags: julia

How do you clear screen while using Julia REPL, using ctrl +L just scrolls down enough for it to look clean, but the variables still hold the same value, is there any alternative other than closing and reopening it?
I came across using shell>clear, but it shows : could not spawn 'clear' https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJFBn.png

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but given you are worried about "variables still holding the same value", I assume that you are looking for a way to clear the workspace of all defined objects to get back the state you would be in if you restarted your Julia session.

If this is indeed what you are after, the answer is this doesn't exist. See related dicsussions on Julia Discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-clear-variables-and-or-whole-work-space/10149/14) and [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-clear-workspace-variables/44095).

Answer (score 2):

I see you're running in Windows, so maybe there's another program with the same shortcut binding and that's why you don't see the REPL's screen cleared. As per this [discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-clear-variables-and-or-whole-work-space/10149/15), `Ctrl + L` should do (in my Linux box with xfce-terminal, it works like that). Otherwise, I'd suggest you post your question in e.g. Julia's [slack group](https://join.slack.com/t/julialang/shared_invite/zt-18trfkbw1-fo8zuPscYlPTJVUHDqf9xA).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## Clear all objects from current workspace

```
workspace()
```

## Write function to garbage collect all threads

```
function gc_all_threads()
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:Threads.nthreads()
        gc_thread(i)
    end
end
```

## Run function

```
gc_all_threads()
```